# small object optimization useless in using std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Many topics told us that use small object like lambda expression could avoid heap allocation when using `std::function`. But my study shows not that way.

This is my experiment code, very simple

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

typedef std::function<int(int, int)> FUNC_PROTO;

class Test
{
public:
    int Add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    FUNC_PROTO functor = [&test](int a, int b) {return test.Add(a, b); };
    cout << functor(1, 2) << endl;
}
```

And I compile it on centos7, with gcc version 4.8.5 20150623
But the valgrind shows this:

```
==22903== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22903==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22903==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 8 bytes allocated
```

Even if I remove the reference capture, just a plain lambda function. It still cost 1 byte heap allocation.

Is there somthing wrong of me to get small object optimization.

**Update:**

Thanks for the repies. I think I should add more detail of my experiment.

In order to eliminate the possible cause of refrence capturing. I removed capture, code like this:

```
FUNC_PROTO functor = [](int a, int b) {return a + b; };
```

Valgrind shows this:

```
==16691==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1 bytes allocated
```

Still 1 byte heap allocation.

I also tried this to eliminate possible influence of lambda itself(which I think not)

```
FUNC_PROTO functor = [](int a, int b) {return a + b; };
FUNC_PROTO functor2 = [](int a, int b) {return a * b; };

FUNC_PROTO test = nullptr;
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        test = functor;
    }
    else
    {
        test = functor2;
    }
}
```

Valgrind shows:

```
==17414==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 12 frees, 12 bytes allocated
```

That could prove that the functors are not fully stack based object.

And this is my build script:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test  -std=c++11 -g -O3 -DNDEBUG
```

This is my valgrind script:

```
valgrind --log-file=valgrind.log --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./test
```

Comment: Guess it's being used by `cout <<`.

Comment: Did you do a debug or release build? Even things like RVO often don't work in debug builds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately no. I remove that cout, still the same.

Comment: I tried pass -DNDEBUG into, but the same. By the way, I also tried -O2, not working.

Comment: did you turn on optimizations? `-O2` / `-O3` ?

Comment: AFAIK, `std::function` applies _type erasure_, which, generally, needs to allocate. Though it can also employ some form of small buffer/object optimization technique. Note that your lambda captures `test`, therefore, it has subobjects. BTW, what is your compiler?

Comment: Could you run valgrind on `cout << Test{}.Add(1, 2) << endl;`? On my system I have 2 allocations with and without using `std::function`.

Comment: @DanielLangr I tried remove that capture, using this test case ``` FUNC_PROTO functor = [](int a, int b) {return a + b; };```  . The result is 1 byte heap allocation.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't measuring allocation by the lambda? Have you tried :  FUNC_PROTO functor = non member function?

Comment: @Evg On my system, your code cost 0 allocs

Comment: Have you tested an empty main? I expect that we have one alloc at startup with the old implementation. Asking questions about an over 10 years old compiler and lib is a bit curious :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older versions of libstdc++, like the one shipped by gcc 4.8.5, seem to only optimise function pointers to not allocate (as seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Pa8rcYMPr)).

Since the `std::function` implementation does not have the small object optimisation that you want, you will have to use an alternative implementation. Either upgrade your compiler or use [`boost::function`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost/function.html), which is essentially the same as `std::function`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did some test on the testcase you gave. The conclusion is this, from GCC version 5.1, small object optimization is supported in std::function. Thanks for your reply!